# Video in which a man follows a string all his life to end in the desert

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I am looking for the video where a young man stumbles upon a string (or cable) and begins to follow it, out of curiosity. He follows it a really long time as you can see him age and grow old.
At the end he reaches a point where the string stops to go up in the sky, in the middle of the desert. He pulls it and a big rock attached to the string crashes him dead.

This video is only a few minutes long and might be a commercial if I remember well.

Also, is there some kind of mythological or hidden meaning?

Comment: Sounds like a comedy sketch (Monty Python?)

Comment: Hmmm I tried looking but All I can find close to this is their old man in Flying circus. It's more like some message "Life is short, don't waste it"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely the short called "The String" (2007) directed by Naomi Wright and produced by Ginita Jimenez.

[image: The String]

Comment: Ok, this must be it though my memory played a trick by mixing it with some other thing I guess. Thank you very much this is awesome ! Did you happen to know/remember it, or did you search for it ? If you searched, how ^^ ?

Comment: @Eregrith I used the query `short film man follows string`